# Pymupdf getTextbox returns empty

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I have tried to retrieve text in a rectangle. This rectangle is retrieved from
Page.getLinks(). when I try to get the text in the rectangle using getTextbox() and getText(“text”, clip=rect). Both methods return Empty string

Answer (score 1):

Try expanding your rectangle's coordinates slightly. The default get_textbox parameter excludes anything intercepting the bounds of the rectangle.

I was having the exact same issue and this solved it.